JFrog Artifactory randomly returns 404 for resources
I struggle with random problem that appears when trying to for example browse artifacts or build info in Artifactory - browser returns 404 Not Found. After one or sometimes more webpage refreshes it loads the content normally. It is not just me since many users report the same problem.
It is Artifactory 7.68.19 behind a Citrix loadbalancer, it was configured as per recommendation for F5 found here - https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-configure-an-f5-load-balancer-for-artifactory-7-x/how-to-configure-an-f5-load-balancer-for-artifactory-7.x
So if URI matches /artifactory then it lands on port 8081 and for the rest it lands on 8082.
Did anybody face similar problem? Are there any useful log files in Artifactory that could help to pinpoint the root cause? Any help is appreciated, thank you!
Reviewed load balancer config with admin - confirmed correct
Restarted artifactory server - did not solve
Verified network rules with admin - all correct

What do you see at the artifactory-request.log or frontend-request.log? Do you see any difference on the requests themselves?
Do you see anything on an .HAR file?

@shaibz Thank you. artifactory-request and frontend-request show only successful (HTTP 200) calls, nothing about 404. In HAR file I could notice the difference that when on first attempt I navigated to artifactory/ui/native/repository/abc/abc.application it throwed me 404 and link changed to artifactory/ui/404 and then I pasted again artifactory/ui/native/repository/abc/abc.application in the browser, hit enter and it moved me to artifactory/ui/api/v1/download/contentBrowsing/repository/abc/abc.application?isNativeBrowsing=true and I was able to access the file.
